# Bag of words: Prediction on new (out-of-sample) data

Tags: r, text-classification, bag-of-words, document-term-matrix

I'm working with a bag of words in R:

```
library(tm)
corpus = VCorpus(textsource)
dtm = DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
dtm = as.matrix(dtm)
```

I use the matrix `dtm` to train a lasso model.

Now I want to predict new (unseen) text. The problem is, that I need to generate a new `dtm` (for prediction) with the same matrix columns as the original `dtm` used for model training.

Essentially, I need to populate the original `dtm` (as used for training) with new text.

Example: `"original text"` would yield a `dtm` used for taining:

```
original | text
1          1
```

While new (unseen) text, e.g. `"new text"` should yield a `dtm` for prediction:

```
original | text
0          1
```

**Q:** What is the most efficient way to populate an existing document term matrix / bag of words with new (text) data in R?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630627/how-to-recreate-same-documenttermmatrix-with-new-test-data

Comment: Looks good even if it is a bit of a hack. Thanks for pointing me to this!

Comment: Ah, now I see: the correct option to "map" the dict is `dictionary=Terms(crude1.dtm)`... Great!!!